# FluidSynth() output volume is too low

Tags: python, midi, fluidsynth

in my python script i am using fluidSynth to convert .mid files to .wav files

```
fs = FluidSynth()
fs.midi_to_audio('myfile.mid', 'myfile.wav')
```

fluidSynth successfully converts **myfile.mid** to **myfile.wav** and saves the output, everything goes well.

**the problem is the output volume is too low**

i saw in fluidSynth documentation is that i can insert option `-g` or `--gain` to fluildSynth to increase the default volume of 0.2

so in the `FluidSynth()` instance, in the python script, how can i pass the -g option  to increace output volume?!

any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using midi2audio, I'm not sure you're able to pass fluidsynth options in that. Since you have fluidsynth installed you could call it directly using the subprocess module and then you have access to all the options including gain.

Example setting the gain to 5:

subprocess.run(['fluidsynth', '-ni', '-g', '5', 'path to soundfont', 'myfile.mid', '-F', 'myfile.wav'])

This will make it louder. Gain isn't necessarily the same as volume but I don't understand enough about sound engineering to tell the difference.

Answer (score 0):

This solution works very well. In your python code you also need to
`import subprocess`
subprocess is not built into python and needs an import to work successfull.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Using the `pyFluidSynth` library, it is possible to set the gain directly.

On your `Synth` instance, for example:

```
synth.setting('synth.gain', 0.6)
```

I am using it through `sf2_loader` and this solved my low volume issue.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the version of pyFluidSynth you can set the gain in different ways.  I´m using this
fl = fluidsynth.Synth(20.0,44100)
where 20.0 is the gain level.  It's minimum level is 0.5.

This code plays a chord.  You can set the gain level:

```
import time
import numpy
import pyaudio
import fluidsynth

pa = pyaudio.PyAudio()
strm = pa.open(
    format = pyaudio.paInt16,
    channels = 2, 
    rate = 44100, 
    output = True)

s = []

fl = fluidsynth.Synth(20.0,44100)
fl.set_chorus(1,5.0,3.0,10,1)

s = numpy.append(s, fl.get_samples(44100 * 1))

sfid = fl.sfload("yamahagrandpiano44.sf2")
fl.program_select(0, sfid, 0, 0)

fl.noteon(0, 60, 30)
fl.noteon(0, 67, 30)
fl.noteon(0, 76, 30)
fl.noteon(0, 96, 30)


s = numpy.append(s, fl.get_samples(44100 * 2))

fl.noteoff(0, 60)
fl.noteoff(0, 67)
fl.noteoff(0, 76)
fl.noteoff(0, 96)


s = numpy.append(s, fl.get_samples(44100 * 1))

fl.delete()

samps = fluidsynth.raw_audio_string(s)

print(len(samps))
print('Starting playback')
strm.write(samps)
```